# no response in recieving with arduino uno by nfr905

Tags: wireless

from examples of  RadioHead library .
https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/RadioHead/tree/master/examples/nrf905

Comment: I tried the client and server examples ; the client was fine with no errorrs and the serial monitor showed the demanded data but I had a problem with the recieving side , the Rx led did not light on and nothing in the serial monitor had been showed . 
what's the matter !?
 and I did'nt change anything in both codes .